# Issue with getBM() from Biomart

Tags: dbplyr, biomart, vctrs

I am trying to acquire GO terms for a list of genes in my dataset. The code I use is as follows:

```
all_genes <- c(rownames(vsd))
ensembl <- useMart(biomart = "ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL", 
                   dataset = "mmusculus_gene_ensembl")
go_ids= getBM(attributes=c('external_gene_name', 'go_id', 'namespace_1003'), filters='external_gene_name', values=all_genes, mart=ensembl)
```

But when I run this I receive the following error:
Error in vec_slice(vec_data(x), i) :

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?